# Selecting a random element for a specific key in a Multimap

Tags: c++, std

How can I select a random element for a specific keys in a multimap. For example:

```
multimap<string, string> map;
map.insert(pair<string, string>("Mammal", "Tiger"));
map.insert(pair<string, string>("Mammal", "Chicken"));
map.insert(pair<string, string>("Mammal", "Fox"));
map.insert(pair<string, string>("Fish", "Clown Fish"));
map.insert(pair<string, string>("Fish", "Ray"));
```

In the above, what would be the best way to get a random "Mammal"?

I know I can get the iterators for the "Mammal" so:

```
pair<MultiMapIt,MultiMapIt>iterators = mMultiMap.equal_range("Mammal");
// loop through each... and select one.
```

But I am sure there is a better solution... perhaps using the iterator as numbers..
Thanks

Comment: adding a random number (in the distance between the begin and end of the range returned) is not sufficient?

Comment: not sure how to get `iterators.first` to an `int` to do the random...

Comment: Calculate the `std::distance()` between the two returned iterators and use a RNG to give you a random number by which you can `std::advance()` the iterator(`iterators.first`) - that gives you a random mammal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inserting comments as answer:

1. Get the iterator range - you have this already
2. Calculate the size of the range

   `std::size_t sz = std::distance(iterators.first, iterators.second);`
3. Now generate a random index:

   `std::size_t idx = std::rand() % sz; // stupid example`
4. Move the iterator to the `idx`-th position:

   `std::advance(iterators.first, idx);`

Now `iterators.first` is pointing at a random mammal.

Comment: +1 Although it would be worth noting that this approach, due to map iterators usually not being random access iterators, has linear complexity in the size of the range (even if this is negligable in most cases, as you rarely have a multimap with thousands or more duplicates).